# Supervised learning for image segmentation

Tags: machine-learning, python, image-classification

Hello I am new to Applied ML and trying to solve a problem where I have given several images with few patches in it and masked images where these patches are classified/extracted as training data.Given that i need to use ML to train network such that It can generate those masked images for test data set.
I would like to know which technique will be best suitable in Both the cases where I want to use Python extended libraries like Scikit or Using just Numpy and Scipy.
Thanks in advance

Comment: The usual meaning of "several" is "about 5". Do you really have less than 10 training images? Could you give a little more detail, and if it is OK to share a typical original plus masked image it might help to choose an algorithm. If you really have just 5 training images, then you are not going to be able to train a classifier from scratch.

Comment: I have around 164 images each of size 128 x 128.
Train data contains images similar to this http://www.sweethaven02.com/MDSeries/MD0852/framew55.jpg
and masked images are B/w images where the purple area is extracted as white.it is basically a problem where I need to classify purple patches and the rest in masked image!

Comment: I don't think you want ML techniques for this task. I think you probably want some form of region detection based on colour values. Try something like this: https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/

Comment: Even I thought initially but It is said to use ML  or AI technique to approach the problem. Moreover why the output files are given along!

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you use Python with Ski-Image for Image Related operation. For Machine Learning typically for Deep Learning, you should use [Keras](https://keras.io/) with theano/Tensorflow backend with GPU capabilities whichever suits you.

In order to generate masked images, you should use data augmentation.[Data Augmentation Documentation for Keras](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/)